# for each of the following find all values for which the following integral is improperly integrable on $I$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

We have $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}, I=(0,1)$$

Taking the anti derivative:

$$\frac{1}{(1-p)x^{1-p}}$$

I get 1 but the back of the book says when p is less than 1

Answer (score 1):

Let $N \in \Bbb{N}$ and $p \geq 1$

Then $$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x^p}dx \geq \sum_{n=1}^N \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{x^p}dx=$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^Nn^p(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) =\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n^p}{n(n+1)}\geq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n^p}{2n^2},\forall N \in \Bbb{N}$$

But  $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n^p}{2n^2} \to^{N \to \infty}  +\infty$$ since $p\geq 1$

So the integral diverges to infinity for $p \geq 1$

For $p<1$ it is easy to see that converges.